# I cannot Select an Element with the AndroidFindBy

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, appium-android, appium-java

I am fairly new to Appium and i am currently working on UI testing of an application. I want to click an element but it is not visible until you scroll down the page.

I have tried using the command below but it does not work for me

driver.findElement(By.xpath("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("WebView").instance(0))")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace "By.xpath" with "MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator".

See Appium's [documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/tutorial/swipe/android-simple/).